# Dialog for "Enable Device Admin" not showing when Starting Activity

Tags: java, android, device-admin

I've run into a pretty confusing issue.

I have an app that should be registered as a Device Administrator.  I have followed several tutorials on-line that explain how to accomplish this.  It was working just fine when I was using Eclipse, but since switching to Android Studio when I install the app I do not get the "Enable Device Admin" dialog as expected when running my app.  If I look at Phone Administrators in my phone settings it will show my app, but it won't be checked as an admin. Here are the applicable sections of code.  Any insight would be great!

androidmanifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:name="com.foo.receivers.AdminReceiver"
              android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/my_admin"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

My Receiver Class:

```
    public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver
    {   
        @Override  
        public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        //Some Code Here
        }

        @Override  
        public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            //Some Code Here
        }  

        @Override  
        public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {  
        }   

        @Override  
        public void onPasswordChanged(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {  
             //Some Code here    
        }  

         @Override  
        public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {  
             //Some Code Here
        }   

        @Override  
        public void onPasswordSucceeded(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {  
             //Some Code Here
        }     
    }
```

My Class that actually enabled Device Admin:

```
    public class DeviceManager
    {
        private DevicePolicyManager deviceManger;  
        private ActivityManager activityManager;  
        private ComponentName compName;

        public DeviceManager(Context context)
        {
            deviceManger =  DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);  
            compName = new ComponentName(context, MyAdmin.class);
        }    

        public void registerAdmin(Activity activity)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,compName);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Administrative Rights need to be granted to DriveLock to enable phone locking.");
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent,0);

        }
    }
```

A Sample Call to the class:

```
    DeviceManager manager = new DeviceManager(context);
    manager.registerAdmin(myActivity);
```

I'm really confused as to why I am not seeing the Device Admin dialog.  Five dollars to whoever solves it!  Haha.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK it looks like I get to keep my five dollars :).  When migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio I did a slight refactor/reorg.  As part of this I ended up with two classes named MyAdmin.java (each in a different package).  The MyAdmin class is the class that extends DeviceAdminReceiver.  Having two of these is what was causing the issue.  Once I deleted one of the duplicate class everything started working as expected.

[image: Packages]